# Cloud computing with country-specific region for Switzerland

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, cloud-computing, hardware

Are there any cloud computing services that allow for processing and storing data exclusively in Switzerland? Are there any that have machine-learning-specific functionality?

Most do not seem to have this capability:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/

In some industries, such as finance, this is a strict requirement for regulatory and compliance reasons.

Comment: I guess the first one even does not allow for storing data.

Comment: @Media, that is an interesting point. I suppose then, that I would also need to consider the regions for the compute and storage services separately? I was thinking about the entire Google Cloud ecosystem. https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Comment: Actually as far as I know `Colab` is different from *Cloud Services*. Moreover because of probable bottlenecks I do guess that computation and storage features may be located near each other because transferring large scale data is so much time consuming. Anyway, yes. That's the point that you have to consider.